# One-liner to delete any line that starts with a number not followed by a delimiter

Tags: python, regex, windows, text, sed

This two-line python code works. Can it be made concise? Thanks.

```
temp_test_001 = '''
Test 1,2,3,
41
Test 5,6,7,
8800
8800 8800 
8800.
8800.0
8,800
Test 9,10
Test 11,12
'''.split('\n')

lines = '' 
for line in enumerate(temp_test_001): lines += [line[1] + '\n',''][line[1].isnumeric()]
print(lines)

Test 1,2,3,
Test 5,6,7,
8800 8800 
8800.
8800.0
8,800
Test 9,10
Test 11,12
```

Comment: What are the rules for keeping and for deleting lines?

Comment: `sed '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/d' file` will delete any line that is just digits. Testing this with `[[:digits:]][[:digits:]]` surprised me, as apparently `:digits:` includes not just `.` but also the space char. It did, however, let your `Test 1,2,3` etc pass thru. Bad reaction to your question? I've seen many worse. Maybe you should have hightlighted you only wanted the `14` line to disappear and by extension, you could have illustrated your problem with 3-4 lines sample data, but at least you had sample data and didn't try to verbally describe your problem ....

Comment: To improve your `sed` foo, see the [Sed Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)... I the future keep in mind that a good question is 1) small set of sample data that covers any special cases and if required a "reject this record" sample 2) expected output from that sample data, 3) your (what you think should work) best attempt at code, 4) current output from your code 5) exact text of any error messages. Use proper `code/data/output/exactTxtOfErrMsgs` formatting so readers can easily copy/paste code to their environment. ....

Comment: Please read  the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash). Your Q is actually pretty good on this score, but I offer that advice because questions like that get the fastest and clearest help. Good luck.

Comment: *"My attempt (removes all numbers)"* . So you have learned now to to apply the `/g` modifier on the `s/` command (-;. Do your tests like `echo "888.9" | sed 's/..../..../` and focus on one issue at a time. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ugly one-liner in Python

```
txt = '''
Test 1,2,3,
41
Test 5,6,7,
8800 
8800 8800 
8800.
8800.0
8,800
Test 9, 10
Test 11, 12
'''

print('\n'.join([line for line in txt.split('\n') if not all(map(lambda x: x in '0123456789', line.strip()))]))

Test 1,2,3,
Test 5,6,7,
8800 8800 
8800.
8800.0
8,800
Test 9, 10
Test 11, 12
```

You can execute it from the shell as one-liner using

```
python -c "import sys; print(''.join([line for line in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines() if not all(map(lambda x: x in '0123456789', line.strip()))]))" text.txt
```

Where `text.txt` is your input text file.

Comment: The OP indicated that his intent is reading from a file. Where's that in your answer?

Comment: @Paolo, I have added a solution for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```bash
$ awk '$0 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $0}' file
Test 1,2,3,
Test 5,6,7,
8800 8800
8800.
8800.0
8,800
Test 9, 10
Test 11, 12
```

so if the entire line matches only numbers it is not printed.